# Translating Wordpress Login Page with WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml

We are building a custom theme with BeaverBuilder for the front end and custom theme for logged in users. We have been able to translate both the beaver builder front end and the custom theme part. We are having a hard time translating the login page and I'm wondering if there is a filter or hook I can use to get the login and forgot password pages translated. I understand there is an ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE variable that is set as the user navigates the site. Can I use it somehow to translate those pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [login hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Login_Hooks) to update the login page with your custom items.